# Showing v-menue's selected option in another part of the application. Vuetify

Tags: javascript, vue.js, menu, vuetify.js

So I have a v-menu with some options. Now I want to display the selected option in another part of my app (same component). I tried to do it using v-model but it doesn't work. What's the best way to do it?

This is the code for the v-menu and where I want to display the selected option:

```
<v-menu bottom transition="scale-transition" >
  <v-btn slot="activator">​ 
      28
  </v-btn>
  <v-list>
    <v-list-tile
      v-for="(item, index) in PIFBitems"
      :key="index"
      v-model="hasan"
      @click="boardSwitch('shoPFIB', index)"
      >
       <v-list-tile-title>{{ item.title }}</v-list-tile-title>
    </v-list-tile>
  </v-list>
</v-menu>
.
.
.
  <p class="chipPam13"
  >{{this.hasan}}</p>
.
.
```

This is the script code:

```
data() {
  return {
    hasan:'',
    PIFBitems:[
    {title: empty},
    {title: PIFB}
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use `hasan` rather than `this.hasan` in your HTML:

```
<p class="chipPam13">{{hasan}}</p>
```

Or if `v-model` doesn't work, you can try to set `hasan` value at `boardSwitch` function:

```
...
methods: {
    boardSwitch (firstArg, secondArg, value) {
        ...
        this.hasan = value
    },
    ...
}
```

Please don't forget to add third argument to your function call in HTML:

```
<v-list-tile
  v-for="(item, index) in PIFBitems"
  :key="index"
  v-model="hasan"
  @click="boardSwitch('shoPFIB', index, item.title)"
  >
   <v-list-tile-title>{{ item.title }}</v-list-tile-title>
</v-list-tile>
```

Comment: Very clean and polite response. Thank you :)